# Is there any library that provides containers for non-copyable types that are not default-contructible?

Tags: c++, c++03

I am looking for a library that provides containers like `std::array` (compile-time fixed size, but without support for aggregate initialization) and `std::vector` (variable size, continuous memory) that work for types that are non-copyable and not default-constructible.

Specifically, I want to be able to pass a set of functions to the constructor that are used to obtain the arguments for the constructors of the contained objects. Something like `emplace_back`, but as a constructor and using lazily evaluated arguments.

Here is a (naturally not working) example:

```
class stubborn_type : boost::noncopyable {
public:
    explicit stubborn_type(int value)
    : value(value)
    {}

private:
    const int value;
};

struct generate_values {
    generate_values(int initial_value = 0)
    : current_value(initial_value)
    {}

    int operator()() {
        return current_value++;
    }
private:
    int current_value;
};

/* This should create a vector containing 10 elements initialized with the values
   [0..9] in order. */
magic::vector<stubborn_type> data(10, generate_values());
```

I need the to solution to be compatible with C++03 (since this means no variadic templates I would prefer the Boost approach of using preprocessor magic to generate overloads for different numbers of arguments, but a reasonable fixed limit is fine as well). Does something like this exist? If not, are there any libraries that would help achieve that goal (for instance, [Boost.In Place Factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/in_place_factories.html) is almost useful, but it does not support lazy arguments).

Comment: You should be able to use a `vector<boost::optional<stubborn_type>>` and return `in_place<stubborn_type>` from your generator, except that `optional<stubborn_type>` is non-copyable. The construction within a container would already be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know any ready solution, however, it is not so hard to do it. The outline of the array may look like this

```cpp
#include <cstddef>

typedef char saum;
// smallest addressable unit of memory

namespace magic {

    template<class T>
    class IArray
    {
        T *const _ptr;
        const size_t _length;

    public:

        operator T* () {
            return _ptr;
        }

        size_t length() const {
            return _length;
        }

    private:

        IArray<T>(T* ptr, size_t length)
            : _ptr(ptr), _length(length)
        {}

        template<class S, size_t length>
        friend class Array;
    };


    template<class T>
    class Generator
    {
    public:
        virtual void operator() (T* place) = 0;
    };



    template<class T, size_t length>
    class Array
    {
        saum buffer[sizeof(T) * length];

    public:

        Array(Generator<T>& generate) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
                generate((T*)buffer + i);
        }
        ~Array() {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
                ((T*)buffer)[i].~T();
        }

        operator IArray<T> () {
            return IArray<T>((T*)buffer, length);
        }

        operator T* () {
            return (T*)buffer;
        }
    };

}
```

I'm little tired, so forgive me not thinking out some better names. Nevertheless, it shall do the job. Maybe, the generator solution is not too beautiful, but still gives flexibility. I believe more feathers won't case a problem.

An example

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

class Stubborn
{
public:
    Stubborn(int value) : value(value*2) { }
    const int value;

private:
    Stubborn(const Stubborn&);
    Stubborn& operator=(const Stubborn&);
};



struct StubbornGen : public magic::Generator<Stubborn>
{
    StubbornGen() : current_value(0)
    {}

    void operator() (Stubborn* place) {
        new(place) Stubborn(current_value++);
    }

private:
    int current_value;
};



void f(magic::IArray<Stubborn> stubs)
{
    std::cout << stubs[0].value << stubs[1].value
              << stubs[2].value << stubs[3].value
              << "  " << stubs.length() << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    StubbornGen gen;
    magic::Array<Stubborn, 4> stubs(gen);
    f(stubs);
}
```

**Edit:** Corrected, thanks to DyP, plus the generator tweak.

It is important to define a copy constructor and an assignment operator for the Array, to avoid the problem pointed by DyP. -- How? - depends on what you want. Making them private is a one way. And doing a non-shallow copy is an another. - In the second case, the mechanism of template instantiation should prevent from errors, when applying a non-copiable class to the Array.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1

Comment: But I am not sure is it guarantied by the standard.

Comment: It is. [expr.sizeof]/1: "sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and
sizeof(unsigned char) are 1." :) Also, `typedef` is considered preferable over `#define` -> `typedef char SAUM;`. Please don't include C-headers in C++, rather use the C++ versions -> `#include <cstddef>`

Comment: Hmmmm I think you got some UB here... you create a `magic::Array` (which is a temporary) and then assign it to a `magic::IArray`, which works by converting using `magic::Array::operator IArray<T>`. But this just stores the pointer in the `IArray`, the temporary will get destroyed. You could store a `const&` to extend the lifetime of the temporary; though I'm not sure what's the problem with just using an `magic::Array`

Comment: @DyP, right. I was little tired. -- The Array was sufficient, but wanted to show, what is the IArray for. - Probably in not the most lucky way.

Comment: I thought about this again, some further remarks: if the contained type (`Stubborn`) is non-copyable through copy-construction, one probably shouldn't try to copy its data through the implicitly declared `magic::Array` copy-ctor and copy-assignment-op (i.e. make them private, too). It's also not very good here as the objects stored in `Array::buffer` are created only once but destroyed multiple times if the `Array` has been copied.

Comment: IMO it's preferable to turn the `Array` ctor into a member function template instead of enforcing the generator to be derived from a specific type: `template < typename Gen> Array(Gen& generate) { /*... */`.

Comment: @DyP, first - the copying depends on the policy. I do not know, would someone want to have copiable or non-copiable Array. Given construction is an outline and should be extended. - But, indeed, I should mention it. - Second - IMO forcing to derive from a template generator is a nice way for protection from mistakenly applying a wrong generator to a wrong `Array`. In example, having `class B : public A`, you would be able to apply a generator for `A` to the `Array<B>`, if not having the derivation.

Comment: Ad second: Oh, you're right, in this case a simple template would be error prone (as the generator uses placement new). I think a template plus SFINAE (enforcing a strictly typed member function `void operator()(T*)`) would work. Ad first: If the stored type is non-copyable, it has been made non-copyable for a reason; it's not possible for an object of that type to be copied just by copying the memory it occupies (otherwise it would have a trivial copy ctor). E.g. a file handle with exclusive file access rights - if you copy that handle via "memcpy" and destroy it twice -> UB most probably.

Comment: @DyP, I was not aware of SFINAE. And must admit, it is the ugliest language hack I have seen. The readability and debugging may come poor, because of it. Ad Array's copying: maybe I am wrong, but believe, I have read about this. - The template instantiation mechanism allows to define a copy constructor and an assignment for the Array, which calls the copy constructor and the assignment from the Array's argument type T (this creates a sane copy of the Array). And, while those operations are not instantiated later, there should be no errors, even when T would be non-copiable type.

Comment: "the ugliest language hack I have seen" a really nice description :) (fortunately, there's `static_assert` now) "The template instantiation mechanism..." Except for some rules not applying here, a copy-ctor and a copy-assignment-op are always declared. They may be defined as deleted, e.g. if a data member cannot be copied. If `Array` had a data member of type `T` or of type *array of `T`*, then both would be defined as deleted depending on `T`. But `T` just as a template parameter doesn't impose any restrictions on the copy-ctor and copy-assignment-op.

Comment: I.e. `Array` can always be copied as it only has a data member of type *array of `char`*, but that can be dangerous, because if it's copied, then the stored objects of type `T` (stored in `buffer`) will also be "copied" in the sense that the memory they occupy will be copied. This operation itself is safe, but now you have two `Array`s, where in both dtors those objects will be destroyed. Now imagine `T` was a `std::unique_ptr`, which frees some memory on destruction. In this case, the memory will be freed two times -> UB

Comment: Maybe misunderstand what I mean by _define a copy constructor and an assignment for the Array, which calls the copy constructor and the assignment from the Array's argument type_? E.g. for copy constructor, it means `Array(const Array& other) { for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) new ((T*)buffer + i) T( ((T*)other.buffer)[i] ); }`. -- For my gcc it work. Which is - if T is copiable, then it copies, if not the compiler doesn't complain, until the instantiation of the constructor (like `Array<T,n> a1...; Array<T,n>a2(a1);`). And I believe, have read it is the proper behavior.

Comment: Yes, I think this would work (for copyable `T`), but the assumption is `T` is non-copyable. As you haven't declared a copy-ctor in `Array`, the compiler will implicitly declare one (and define it if it's used). All that will compile w/o the any problems, but it can raise problems at run-time (if the `Array` is copied, see above). Therefore you *have* to prevent the compiler from providing the default copy-ctor (and copy-assignment-op), either by providing an own implementation (which cannot work, as `T` is non-copyable) or declaring them as `private` members (w/o definition, not to be used).

Comment: "And I believe, have read it is the proper behavior." You're right about that - I didn't knew this behaviour before. It's a property of the implicit instantiation of a class template (the declarations of the functions are instantiated, but the definitions only when required; therefore access is only checked if the function is used). But that's beside the point I want to make: you have to provide a custom copy-ctor. You can use the one from your comment, even for non-copyable `T`s (as it would raise a compile-time error if the `Array` is copied).